# adding big amount of jlabels in jpanel quickly

Tags: java, mysql, swing, user-interface

Hi i am using java swing to make java GUI app that fetch data from mysql and after that put each row into JLabel and add this to certain Jpanel.

my problem is when i am fetching more than 4k row the app take 0.3 min to get the process above done and the time increase as the number of rows increased.

i calculated the delay from mysql and it was 20.26 sec for each 60k rows and when i calculated for the app it was almost 2.5 min for the same amount of rows.

so my question is there anything that will speedup my app in terms of (mysql,java).

Comment: Do you need to view all the labels at the same time? You could have multiple pages, and only grab, say 10-20 rows, needed for each page.

Comment: Yes i do but after searching and reading the 2 answers i will not use JLabel i will use JTable because as @SuicideClyde many object creation is expensive and wrong approach, thnx guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> fetch data from mysql and after that put each row into JLabel and add
>   this to certain Jpanel.

- use `JTable`, search for `ResultSetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`

> my problem is when i am fetching more than 4k row the app take 0.3 min
>   to get the process above done and the time increase as the number of
>   rows increased.

- `4k` is over human capabilities to use bunch of data during standard working hours

> i calculated the delay from mysql and it was 20.26 sec for each 60k
>   rows and when i calculated for the app it was almost 2.5 min for the
>   same amount of rows.

- create a batch logics, run `ResultSet` from `SwingWorker`, `publish()` every `100rows` to `ResultSetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`, then user can see 1st 100row quite immediatelly, rest of rows is added from worker thread managed by Swing Worker
- is easy, simple and possible to split one huge Query to set of Queries, create SQL Query with pagination,

Comment: thank you, put i have one question in last answer of your's you mean i will grap each 100 row and after that i will update the Jtable until i finish the query right ?

Comment: not you display batch contains 100 row from one big resultset, then next 100rows 
(and so on untill ended), update to Swing GUI is splitted to the partial updates

Answer (score 3):

Object creation is an expensive process.  I would suggest not creating an individual label for each field you've fetched from your DB.  Is there any reason you've chosen to not use a JTable/TableModel?  It seems like this would be the best tool for representing a table of data in your database.  There are MANY examples of how to use a JTable on the web, so I won't describe that here.

As an experiment to determine if the JLabel creation is contributing to your problem, create a single label for each row instead of one JLabel per field and see how much that improves things.

I also second mKorbel's suggestion to process things in batch if immediate responsiveness is desired.  This allows you to supply some immediate data to your users while querying and presenting the rest of your infomration as it becomes available.

This works great for your large data sets provided the user doesn't need all of the information before being able to make the decision or draw the conclusion required (ie - solving the problem that caused them to queryin the first place).  If this is the case, a busy indicator might be best.

Good luck!